# how to datalink the index with the json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsrender, jsviews

I have the following JSON object which maintain the sequence in it.

```js
var sample={
  "sample": [
    {
      "example": [
        {
          "sequence": 1, 
        },
        {
         "sequence":2
        },
        {
         "sequence":3
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "example": [
        {
         "sequence": 1,
      
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
    };
         $.templates("testingTemplate", "#testingSection");
 
var html=$.link.testingTemplate("#htmlHolder", sample);
$("#insert").click(function(){
var childIndexVal=parseInt($("#childIndex").val());
var x= {
          "sequence": childIndexVal+1,
          "xxx":"yyy"
        };
var parentIndexVal=parseInt($("#parentIndex").val());

$.observable(sample.sample[parentIndexVal].example).insert(childIndexVal,x);
console.log(sample);
});
```

```css
.parentHolder
{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.80/jsviews.js"></script>
<script id="testingSection" type="text/x-jsrender">

{{if sample && sample.length}}
 
 {^{for sample }}
  <div class="parentHolder">
   {^{for example }}
      <div><span data-link="#index+1" ></span>
      <input type="text" value="{{:sequence}}" id="sequence" data-link="#index+1"></div>
    {{/for}}
     </div>
  {{/for}}

 {{/if}}
 </script>
 <div id="htmlHolder">
 
 </div>
 <div class="messages">
 
 </div>
 <span>Parent Index:</span><input type="text" id="parentIndex"/>
 <span>Child Index:</span><input type="text" id="childIndex"/>
 <button id="insert" >Insert</button>
```

so whenever I insert the object it should update the squence accodring to the index.

In the given example, if I am inserting an object into the 1st index of example in sample[0].(consider example array index starts from zero).

So when I am inserting one object into first parameter, the sequence in the remaining object should updated according to the index.

How can I achieve it.

give parent Index as 0 and child index as 1.

expected output,

Note: extra "xxx":"yyy" for differntiation purpose.

```
var sample={
  "sample": [
    {
      "example": [
        {
          "sequence": 1, 
        },
    {
        "sequence": 2, 
         "xxx":"yyy"
    }
        {
            "sequence":3
        },
        {
            "sequence":4
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "example": [
        {
         "sequence": 1,

        }
      ]
    }
    ]
    };
```

**Update:** : tried with *`linkTo`* also.

```
<input type="text"   data-link="linkTo=sequence #index+1" ></div>
```

Still not getting the expected output.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither JsRender nor JsViews will modify the JSON data that they are rendering. This is by design: there are no side-effects on the data...

On the other hand, you can write code to create side-effects on the data, or you can use two-way binding so a user can modify data values. But two-way binding will only change the targetted data value, not other values elsewhere, and will do so only when the user triggers a change event on that `<input>` for example.

In your case you want any observable changes to an `examples` array to trigger changes to all `examples` in the array such as to ensure the `example.sequence` value is always equal to the `index+1` for each `example`. In that case you have to write code to do that.

One way you can achieve that is to add the following code using [observeAll](https://www.jsviews.com/#observeAll):

```
$.observable(sample).observeAll(function(ev, eventArgs) {
  if (ev.type==="arrayChange" && ev.data.observeAll.path().slice(-7)==="example") {
    $.each(ev.currentTarget, function(i, item) {
      $.observable(item).setProperty("sequence", i+1);
    })
  }
});
```

That will ensure that the `sequence` value stays in sync not only for insert, but also when items are removed or for changes in the the order of items, etc.

Comment: @BorisMoore..I am working and still working on the integration part.Sorry for the delay. Once it works  I will mark it as accepted. I have another doubt too.
is there a way,can I  data-link the index with html attribute? For example, <div data-order={^{#index}}>. So whenever I insert the data inside of that example, it will be updated. I read this https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/69. But I am not sure where the solution available.

Comment: Perfectly working . Thanks a lot. Please provide info if this is possible <div data-order="{^{#index}}"> .

Comment: @svk: yes, but not that syntax. You must use data-link syntax. See http://www.jsviews.com/#link-elemattribs. You can write: `data-link="data-order{:#index}"`

Comment: @BorisMoore..sorry to ask to many questions here... if needed I will post this as a seperate question..one more, when I tried to add the condition like this 
`data-link="css-width{(:#index)==0?"6%":""}"`  ..I have to add if 6% if the index is zero .else not. I am getting an error.  The data-order you provided working good.

Comment: That's bad syntax. `data-link="css-width{:#index ? '' : '6%'}"` would make more sense.

Comment: It worked Perfectly .Thanks Borris. I will update my question when I get a chance with your answers. I posted another question seperately which is related with jquery datepicker.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068896/jsrender-how-to-display-calendar-icon-and-make-date-picker-field-read-only